# iPhone Web App Cache Persistence

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, iphone-web-app

How can I write an ASP.NET (C#) application that will render a page can be permanently cached on the iPhone when it is bookmarked as a "Homescreen Icon"?  I have tried setting this on the code behind "Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.MaxValue;" but to no avail.  The server code is still executed every time the home screen icon is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this up through HTML5 cache and app manifest files. Thw WhatWG group has posted a [draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#offline) specification.