# HMTL5 manifest cache and pre load

Tags: html

could someone spread some information on html 5 manifest app cache for me? My question is, if you include an image or file on the manifest, should it load the file immediately and then not have to reload the file any more?

For example, I have a web application where i would like to preload all the images at the beginning, can i include them in the manifest or do i still need to use JS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone else that is curious... a manifest does preload everything that is included but there are couple of things that will effect this which are easily missed.

1. a single error in manifest file means nothing will be cached. eg. if have 20 items in your manifest, and one of those files doesn't exist. The whole manifest will not load.
2. your server (at least apache) needs to be configured to run appcache files. [see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863380/cant-get-simple-html5-manifest-cache-to-work)