# Can you store the entire jQuery library within the application cache in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, caching, html, mobile

Thats pretty much it. Looking for best practice with mobile jQuery caching. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't it be cached by the browser anyway?

Comment: Huh - I wouldn't, but it's an interesting thought

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264367/iphone-web-app-cache-persistence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need really, with the [proper caching headers](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) the browser will already be caching the library.  This isn't HTML5 specific at all, cache headers have been around for quite some time, you can configure them on your site ([see the link for details](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching)) or include the jQuery script from a CDN, for example:

- [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery): http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
- [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx): http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Both of these have the cache headers set appropriately already.

Comment: The need for this comes into play when dealing with mobile devices. For example the iPhone can only cache 25K and the jQuery library is pushing 24K...that's why I want to store it. 

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/

Am I not right for thinking storing it would be beneficial for a mobile web app?

Comment: @Brad - Actually those limits are the *uncompressed* size, so jQuery already violates that, or did. If you read further down you see the iOS 4's cache limit is over 100KB for a simple component, so this isn't the issue it used to be.  Also jQuery's mobile support being around the corner may change things even more.  I would read the updated article: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-browser-cache-limits-revisited/ it's *much* more on point in addressing your concerns :)