# Wireless updating in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an application in the store that has a bunch of `UITableViews`, each has a bunch of items that when selected, load a `UIWebView` that loads a local **HTML** file. The reason I do this is so it allows for viewing when there is no internet access, however it makes it tedious to update.

How would I go about both keeping local files, and keeping web files, so that If I update one on the web it would let the user know there is an 'update' and it can download and overwrite the old file with the new. Is this possible? Like I would make myself a backend to edit my **HTML**, and have a connection to the app so whenever I clicked save the app would know to ask the user to update the files so I don't have to submit to apple for such small updates.

But I still need to allow offline viewing in case they didn't have internet access.

What technologies or techniques would I have to research to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is an html5 concept called [application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).. it directly addresses your problem. With app cache you can cache static content at the client side, which they can view even if they're offline, yet they can update it when the content on the server changes. If you [look around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264367/iphone-web-app-cache-persistence) you'll see people use this for the iPhone as well.

**update:**
*What way would I go about rewriting files on the phone from ones on a server?*

you basically update the cache to do that. from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW1):

> The application cache automatically updates only if the manifest file
>   changes. It does not automatically update if resources listed in the
>   manifest file change. The manifest file is considered unchanged if it
>   is byte-for-byte the same; therefore, changing the modification date
>   of a manifest file also does not trigger an update. If this is not
>   sufficient for your application, you can update the application cache
>   explicitly using JavaScript.

I encourage you to do some reading on html5 local storage just to get the concept of local cache and manifest files etc, then just follow through the instructions on the apple docs.. It's not that difficult.

Comment: What way would I go about rewriting files on the phone from ones on a server?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the content as abbood said but that won't allow you to provide initial offline content.

Another approach would be to use `NSURLProtocol`, which allows you to swizzle a request. For example, if you have a request for "http://google.com", you would be able to either change the URL or load your own content (say from a local directory).